# gray scale background-colored face

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am using android, java and I want to do face detection, gray scale background, rgb face. I am detecting face but cannot convert the faces from gray to rgb.Any suggestion? Thanks
Here is the code:

```
@Override
            public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

                rgb =inputFrame.rgba();
                gray =inputFrame.gray();

                rects =new MatOfRect();

                cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(gray,rects, 1.08,2);


                for(Rect rect :rects.toList())
                {

                    //cropped face
                    Mat submat = gray.submat(rect);

                    Mat rgbsubmat = rgb.submat(rect);


                    Imgproc.cvtColor(submat, submat, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4); 

                    rgbsubmat.copyTo(gray.submat(rect));

                    Imgproc.rectangle(gray,rect,new Scalar(0,255,0),10);


                    submat.release();


                }


                return gray;
            }
```

I am trying to convert sub matrix which has face position gray to rgb form

Comment: What do you mean by saying "gray scale background" ? it is not possible converting from gray scale to bgr

Comment: I mean background should be in gray mode, only faces are colored (rgb) mode, like object detection. But I cannot integrate rgb face into gray background.

Comment: you need to get the mask of face instead of only detection. After getting mask of face then you can copy it to the desired background easily. Mediapipe, rcnn etc. can give you maskedfaces.